# Updating record in winforms using Web API

Tags: c#, winforms, asp.net-core, web-services, webapi

I'm pretty new to entity framework and Web services.

What I'm trying to do is updating records from winforms application by calling update method in Web API.
Httpresponse message returns bad request and doesn't update anything.

There is either a logical error with the code I wrote in api which updates records or the code I wrote in winform. I can't tell where the problem is.

Update method in API

```
[HttpPut]
public async Task <IActionResult> UpdateStatus ([FromBody]BookStatus entity)
{
    var original = Tools.Context.BookStatus. Find(1);
    Tools.Context.Entry (original).CurrentValues.SetValues (entity);
    var result = await Tools.Context.SaveChangesAsync();

    if (result > 0)
        return Ok (result);

    return Badrequest ();
}
```

Winform app where I call update method

```
private async void button3_click (object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    BookStatus status = new BookStatus();
    status.IsAvailable = true;
    
    HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
    clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback=(sender,cert,chain,sslPolicyError)=>{return true;};
    
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
    client.BaseAdress = new Uri ("Https://localhost:5001");
    
    var serialize = JsonConvert.SerializeObject (status);
    var content = new StringContent(serialize,Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");
    var result = await client.PutAsJsonAsync ("api/BookStatus/UpdateStatus",content);
    Message.Text = result.StatusCode.ToString ()";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your codes and it seems that there was someting wrong with PutAsJsonAsync method ,and the webapi could not get the value of bookstatus.
[image: Result1]

I modified the codes in your winform client,and the webapi could get the value

```
private  void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BookStatus status = new BookStatus();
            status.Id = 1;
            status.IsAvailable = true;
            HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
            clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyError) => { return true; };
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
            var result1 = client.PutAsJsonAsync<BookStatus>("https://localhost:44318/WeatherForecast", status).Result;
           
        }
```

Result:
[image: Result2]

And if you need help for your codes in your webapi project,you could tell me more details of your project such as your model class and Dbcontext